# lim sup of maximum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

I am struggling in evaluating the maximum of a function, for which I need an  asymptotic, which I know how it is behaving. So I am trying to avoid the calculation of the maximum.

More precisely, I have the following setup: I have $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, with $f(n) \to \infty$, $g(n) \to 0$ and $f(n) g(n) \to 0$.

Now, I am wondering whether the following equality holds:

$\limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) \max_{k \geq n} g(k) ) =  \limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) g(n) )$

My argument is the following: the maximum of $g$ is taken over the set $ \{ n, n+1, \ldots \} $. W.l.o.g let assume that the maximum of $g$ is taken at $\tilde{k}:=n+a$ with $a \in \mathbb{N}$, then

$\limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) \max_{k \geq n} g(k) ) =  \limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) g(n+a) ) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) g(n) )$

Is that correct?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: No, the argument is not valid. There are problems with both of your equalities.

Comment: @Adam Robinson Thank you for the comment. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $f(n)g(n)\to 0 \implies \limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) g(n) ) = 0.$

Here is a counter-example to the proposition in the question:

$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
 \log(n)&\text{if}\, n\text{ odd }\\
 n&\text{if}\, n\text{ even}\\
\end{cases}
$

$
g(n)=
\begin{cases}
 1/n&\text{if}\, n\text{ odd }\\
 2^{-n}&\text{if}\, n\text{ even}\\
\end{cases}
$

Then we do have $f(n)\to\infty,\ g(n)\to 0,$ and $f(n)g(n)\to 0.$

But $\limsup_{n \to \infty} ( f(n) \max_{k \geq n} g(k) ) = 1\neq 0.$